# Roblox: BindToClose works, PlayerRemoving does not

Tags: roblox, datastore

I am trying to store CFrame X, Y, and Z data into DataStore so that the player can start off where they left off. I am testing by trying to save hardcoded values.

The loading of data using PlayerAdded works fine.

For some reason, the SetAsync() in PlayerRemoving wasn't completing when the player leaves in game or in studio. The weird thing is that when I added BindToClose, the save function runs correctly when in Studio but not in game.

If anyone can tell me why, I'd be very grateful.

```
local function save(plr)
    local data = {
        CFrameX = -1232;
        CFrameY = 1232;
        CFrameZ = -1235;
    }

    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        MandoSimStore:SetAsync(plr.UserId.."-Location_StorageData", data)
    end)

    if success then
        print("Successfully saved data!")
    else
        warn("ERROR: "..errormessage)
    end
end

local gameShutDown = false

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    wait(0.1)
    if not gameShutDown then
        save(plr)
    end
end)

game:BindToClose(function()
    gameShutDown = true
    for _, plr in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        save(plr)
    end
end)
```

Comment: You might have a timing issue. It could be that the game is shutting down before your data is properly saved. To debug, try adding a `wait(10)` to the  [`game:BindToClose`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/DataModel/BindToClose) function.

Comment: Just tried it and the game still doesn't save in game, but does save in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

`wait(1)`

It worked for me